# What is the easiest way to use Google AJAX Language API to detect language with PHP?

Tags: php, detection, google-language-api

There is an easy way to use the Google AJAX Language API to detect language with PHP without use any library or a giant framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats is easy,

```
function detect_language($string) {
   $response = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/uds/GlangDetect?v=1.0&q=" . urlencode($string));
   $response = json_decode($response, true);
   if ($response['responseStatus'] == 200) {
       return $response['responseData']['language'];
   } else {
       return "tw";
   }
}
```